# Bad Design? Use Abstract Class Collection to Include Concrete Children

Tags: c#, abstract-class

I'm wanting to properly explore/understand implementation of abstract classes in my latest web application I'm writing. However, while I find it amazing that I can instantiate an abstract class with a value of that of a concrete class, I am wondering if this is not a good way to do things, since I can't seem to call on properties in the child concrete class.

I've managed to create a base class IEnumerable collection that contains two ILists of concrete children. While the concrete children share the same type, the idea was to call the concrete children properties in the web page if I need to. Of course, I have a feeling that this design is not really the way to go for my goals.

Class for abstract class:

```
 public abstract class MasterTicket
    {
        public Guid id{ get; set; }
        public DateTime openTime{ get; set; }
        public DateTime closeTime{ get; set; }
        public bool active{ get; set; }
        public string summary{ get; set; }
        public string description{ get; set; }
        public DateTime updateTime{ get; set; }
        //TODO: Create foreign key relationship to user model
        public Guid userUpdateId{ get; set; }
        //TODO: Create foreign key relationship for tickets from other systems
        public Guid externalAppId{ get; set; }
        //TODO: Create foreign key relationship to user model
        public Guid userOpenId{ get; set; }
        public Guid userOwnerId{ get; set; }
        public int timesUpdated{ get; set; }
        public DateTime expectedCompletionTime{ get; set; }
        public DateTime actualCompletionTime{ get; set; }
        public List<MasterTicketItem> masterTicketItems{ get; set; }
        }
```

Class for concrete child class:

```
public class ApptTaskTicket : MasterTicket
    {
        public DateTime currentApptTime;
        public string patientName;
        //TODO: Create foreign relationship
        public Guid subjectPrsnlId;
        public string patientPhone;
        public string patientEmail;
        public string preferredContactMethod;
    }
```

Example controller:

```
public class QueueController : Controller
    {
        private static readonly IList<MasterTicket> tickets;

        private static readonly IEnumerable<MasterTicket> combined;

        static QueueController()
        {
            tickets = new List<MasterTicket>
            {
                new ApptTaskTicket
                {
                    id = Guid.NewGuid(),
                    summary = "Foopy",
                    description = "Please set up Foop Dawg."
                },
                new ApptTaskTicket
                {
                    id = Guid.NewGuid(),
                    summary = "Milk man",
                    description = "Milkman here I come"
                },
                new ApptTaskTicket
                {
                    id = Guid.NewGuid(),
                    summary = "InMode Presentation",
                    description = "Upcoming presentation next month"
                },
            };

            CalendarQuickStart eventFetcher = new CalendarQuickStart();

            IList<MasterTicket> addAppts = eventFetcher.LoadAppointmentTasks();

            combined = tickets.Concat(addAppts);

            tickets.Concat(addAppts);
        }
        // GET: Queue
        public ActionResult Queue()
        {

            return View(combined);
        }
    }
```

View page rendering this list in a table:

```
@model IEnumerable<AffirmativeServiceSystem.Models.MasterTicket>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Queue";
}

<h2>Queue</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        @*<th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.openTime)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.closeTime)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.active)
        </th>*@
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.summary)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.description)
        </th>
        @*<th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.updateTime)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.userUpdateId)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.externalAppId)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.userOpenId)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.userOwnerId)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.timesUpdated)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.expectedCompletionTime)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.actualCompletionTime)
        </th>*@
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        @*<td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.openTime)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.closeTime)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.active)
        </td>*@
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.summary)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.description)
        </td>
        @*<td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.updateTime)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.userUpdateId)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.externalAppId)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.userOpenId)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.userOwnerId)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.timesUpdated)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.expectedCompletionTime)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.actualCompletionTime)
        </td>*@
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.id }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.id }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.id })
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

Can include calendar code function later if needed, but for right now I think it's fine.

I expected to be able to call on both abstract and concrete properties of a child concrete class, but in fact I just see properties of the base MasterTicket class when I try using Intellisense to write in the code for the resulting view page. Should I be using multiple models when say, trying to use different child concrete classes like different ticket types of a base ticket? Idea is to have one concrete class be for appointment confirmations from a calendar, and another for support-like incident items.

Appreciate your thoughts in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I fully understand your problem, but I can you give a few tips. This is not really a response, but it would be too messy to post it as a comment.

Tips:

- Do not create an abstract class without any abstract property or function.

  When you need a common parent for more classes *(where the parent should not be initialised)*, use protected constructor.
- There is no meaning to create a parent or abstract class, when this parent has only a single child.
- The real meaning of abstract class is to implement functionality without specification.

See this simple example of "Reader":

```
public abstract class Reader
{
  public int ReadByte()
  {
    byte[] value = new byte[1];
    int read = Read(value, 0, 1);
    if (read == 0)
    {
      return -1;
    }

    return value[0];
  }

  public abstract int Read(byte[] value, int offset, int count);
}

public class DiskReader : Reader
{
  // TODO: implement reading from disk
  public override int Read(byte[] value, int offset, int count) => throw new System.NotImplementedException();
}

public class PortReader : Reader
{
  // TODO: implement reading from serial port
  public override int Read(byte[] value, int offset, int count) => throw new System.NotImplementedException();
}

public class NetworkReader : Reader
{
  // TODO: implement reading from network connection
  public override int Read(byte[] value, int offset, int count) => throw new System.NotImplementedException();
}
```

There is no real implementation, but you should get the point. When you do not use some abstract functions from the abstract class, there is no need to create an abstract class. See the use of not implemented function in `ReadByte` function.

The same goes with properties. When you do not make use of not implemented function, then it would be better to use a interface.

And to your question: "why can you see child properties"

It is simple. When you have a parent class, you can not see the child properties. Only parent defined methods and properties are visible for parent class. You need to retype to your child class to use it as a child class with all methods and properties.

Using a parent has a meaning when you need more children and there is a function, that can be used on all children with the same properties/functions.

Comment: Hi @Julo, that helps, thanks for that post. Can I ask you - if I was to create a ticket family, a base parent that maybe is concrete along with children that that are concrete, like a base ticket that has universal properties, and then a support ticket and a scheduling ticket as children - would there be a good purpose to still have a base abstract class? I'm still struggling to understand this as I read through online documentation and such.

Comment: When you do not make use of some abstract functionality, I would recommend to use a standard class with a protected (empty) constructor. The base class has a meaning when you have more children, but use `abstract` keyword only when you need it to be abstract *(used, but not implemented functions/properties)*.